# How go to top of UIView on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiscrollview

I put UIScrollView on View.
UIScrollView includes a UIView Customed.

When I click a button, I hope to see UIView's top point.

When I used UITableView, my using code is like this :

```
[self.tableListView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
```

But, this code is able to work UIView on UIScrollView.

```
 [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0 )];
```

This code is found through web searching. 
But, this code doesn't work.

In other words, I want to see top of UIView on UIScrollview not top of UIScrollView.

Thanks!~~~

Comment: `scrollRectToVisible` is a UIScrollView method. You can use it.

Comment: @beryllium Thanks!! But, I did known that ScrollRectToVisible is a UIScrollView method. What I want is to see top of UIView on scrollView not top of scrollView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scrollRectToVisible is also available for UIScrollView

Get the frame of the UIView and and use it as a parameter

EDIT:

Could try:

```
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:myView.frame animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks!! :) You're right!!~ but, I think that my problem is because of other one. re-Thanks!!